# Creating div container in DOJO

Tags: dojo

I want to create the DIV container and format the container with shadow, and other nice look and feel. Because the page will have multiple containers and each will have the different data. I want to do that with DOJO, which component is most suitable for that?

Answer (score 0):

As I understand you, you want to create a div element and style it. Then you should look into dojo/dom-construct and dojo/dom-style